# How to create a custom delete folder in Outlook 2016?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, gmail, microsoft-outlook-2013, trash, gmail-imap

With Outlook 2007 I could go into account settings and choose my own folder where deleted items can go - the reason was to keeps the deleted emails forever, because Google (GMAIL) purges it every month. How do I do this in Outlook 2016 as the option in advanced settings is gone! I Googled and can't find a answer.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this functionality was removed in Outlook 2013/2016. You can't change this folder anymore.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this? It would make this a much better answer ...

Comment: You can see it for yourself in IMAP account settings.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I save my deleted emails now as GMAIL permanently deletes it after a month!

Comment: Backup them periodically to a local PST.